# Best practice to inject variables from html into vue.js?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a vue.js app running within a php-generated page.
The vue app is deployed as static js/css files. The html-file with the corresponding `<div id="app">` is generated by php. What is the best practice to inject variables from withhin php, via html, into vue?

I could think of either binding them as data-attribute to some html elements (which would be a rather dirty hack), or by generating a `<script>` segment to hold my variables - in which case I'm not sure about scoping.the variables scope and correct declaration.

Thanks

EDIT: The data I want to inject is the base url and the credentials for vue-initiated ajax requests, so I can't get those data via ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Szia Zsolt

There are several ways to do this, but the way I've done this is by wrapping the Vue component/app in a custom function before export

It looks something like this

```
import MyApp from './MyApp.vue';

export const mountApp = (el, props) =>
  new window.Vue({
    el,
    render: h => h(MyApp, {props}),
  });
```

This allows you to define a component/app like this

```html
<!-- load vue dependency -->
<script src="vue.js"></script>

<!-- load app code -->
<script src="/dist/app.js"></script>

<!-- create a div to for mounting the app/component-->
<div id="app"></div>

<!-- mount an instance of app to dom element and pass props -->
<script>
  mountApp('#app', {
    api: '/api', // <== add whatever config from the backend template with json_encode
  });
</script>
```

I've found this to be the easiest way to provide Vue components (widgets) to an external environment. Wrapping the mounting functionality inside a function allows you to call mounting on demand.
The only caveat I'll point out (besides assuming your needs are same as mine) is that my setup is using rollup instead of webpack, so I can't guarantee you that the same code will work from webpack the same way, and you may need to mount the function onto the window global. Instead of `export const mountApp = ...` might need to do `window['mountApp'] = ...`

Answer (score 1):

I struggled for 2 days to get this to work, but I could not.

In the end I opted for generating a cookie from the server side and read it from my vue.js application. very easy and got to work in 10 minutes.

1. install the cookie package

   npm install vue-cookies
2. import in the main.js file

   import Vue from "vue";

   import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';

   import App from "./App.vue";

   Vue.use(VueCookies);
3. Then use it in your component

   date:function(){

   return{

   myvariable: this.$cookies.get("myVariable")

   }
   }

full details here:
https://reactgo.com/vue-get-cookie/